# window.scrollTo(0,0) is not working in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I'm trying to make a form where click on 'Next' will scroll the page to top
i tried `window.scrollTo(0,0);` and `this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0])` from @angular/common
and it didnt work.
any ideas? thank you

Comment: You should try to do it with body element. document.body.scrollTop = 0

Comment: More details and context please.

Answer (score 2):

try you do something like this.

**HTML**

```
<p *ngFor="let item of list">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer varius imperdiet urna vitae imperdiet. Nullam luctus tortor
  a odio sollicitudin auctor. Nulla suscipit iaculis magna, ac cursus nisi porta ut. Suspendisse vestibulum, tortor non pellentesque
  hendrerit, est orci laoreet sem, nec luctus mauris lectus quis turpis. Suspendisse at nunc sit amet lacus vestibulum aliquet.
  Proin dignissim fermentum sollicitudin. Integer consectetur nec justo in mattis. Duis a magna aliquet, finibus sapien sed,
  feugiat orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc ipsum sapien, sollicitudin in sagittis sed, tincidunt in sapien. Aliquam
  ornare semper cursus. Nam vitae auctor dolor. Morbi rutrum lacus quam, in commodo erat hendrerit in. Curabitur blandit
  rhoncus tempor.
</p>

<p>
  <button type="button" (click)="scrollToTop()">Scroll to top</button>
</p>
```

**Component**

```
list: string[] = Array(10).fill('test');

  scrollToTop(): void {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```